# Angular ng-select not pre selecting the value on dynamic control

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ngselect

I have a requirement to add city dynamically using ng-select because i need search option while entering city name. Lets say i have two city name saved in the new form and whil doing edit i have to load the two cities in two different ng-select For ex: ng-select should select on page load for the first control(ng-select)newyork and second control(texas) and goon.

```html
<div *ngFor="let savedEntry of savedEntries; let i = index;">
  <ng-select [(ngModel)]="savedEntry.name" [id]="'city-id' + i" name="city">
    <ng-option value="">Select</ng-option>
    <ng-option *ngFor="let city of cities" [value]="city">
      {{ city}}
    </ng-option>
  </ng-select>
</div>
```

sample data

```
  public savedEntries: any[] = [
    { id: 1, name: 'chicago' },
    { id: 2, name: 'NewYork' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Texas' }
  ];

  public cities: string[] = ['SanDiego', 'NewYork', 'Texas', 'Ohio', 'chicago', 'Houston', 'Phoenix'];
```

Here im trying to preselect the default city but it throws an error that ng-option doesnt support  option. Any ideas to solve this issue?

Comment: Your [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-yyjihb?file=src%2Fmain.ts) looks fine.